# Does each metamagic effect on a spell add a full round to the casting time?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic

The PHB, page 88 states about metamagic feats that spontaneous usage of one metamagic feat increases the casting time to a full round action, or an additional full-round action if the original effect takes longer than a standard action to activate.

If a second metamagic feat is used in conjunction with a single spell, does that add extra time beyond the first? Once the first metamagic feat is added, the effect has a longer casting time... so a second metamagic feat should possibly add an additional full-round to the time....

The book does not seem to clearly state either way.

Comment: “Powers manifested using metapsionic feats take the same time as manifesting the powers normally unless the feat description specifically says otherwise.”

Comment: Thanks for the psionics quote... which is odd phraseology considering the problem with psionic focus.

Answer (score 4):

### It takes only one full-round regardless of the number of feats

A sorcerer spell which has one or more metamagic feats consumes a single full-round action, regardless of the number of metamagic feats applied. This is clarified by the *Rules Compendium*, p. 12, "Spontaneous Metamagic Spells":

> Spontaneous casters, including those who normally prepare spells but can spontaneously cast particular spells, must take more time to cast a metamagic spell—a spell enhanced by **one or more metamagic feats**. If a spell's normal casting time is 1 standard action, casting a metamagic version of the spell is a full-round action for a spontaneous spellcaster.